# Удаление старых меток на Яндекс Карты

Tags: ajax, javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть карта Яндекс, на которой отображается некое число меток.
За это отвечает вот эта функция:

```
    setInterval(function() {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/1.php",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  // Выводим координаты из 1.php
                  success: function(data){
                     //var a = data;
                      var json ='[{"login":"37","la":"48.310736","lo":"38.043989"},{"login":"399","la":"48.313092","lo":"37.973239"},{"login":"140","la":"48.300127","lo":"38.017115"},{"login":"1209","la":"48.308369","lo":"38.021465"},{"login":"142","la":"48.308157","lo":"38.025267"},{"login":"122","la":"48.331019","lo":"38.105643"},{"login":"3129","la":"48.300707","lo":"38.020754"},{"login":"3138","la":"48.34084","lo":"37.972458"},{"login":"190","la":"48.334623","lo":"38.052168"}]';
                      var a = [] ; 
                      a = JSON.parse(json);
                     for (var i=0;i<a.length;++i) {
                     var login = a[i].login,la = a[i].la,lo =a[i].lo;
                     var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
                    // Координаты метки
                    [la, lo],{iconContent:login}, {preset: 'twirl#redStretchyIcon'});       
                    // Добавление метки на карту
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                    },
                  error: function(){alert('Проблема с загрузкой скрипта');}
                    });
            }, 5000);
```

Нужно реализовать механизм удаления старых меток.
Как это грамотно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

```
Отвечу сам на свой вопрос
1. Необходимо добавить метки в коллекцию
myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
myCollection.add(myPlacemark);

2.Удалить коллекцию путем вызова метода .removeAll()
3.Обновить слой методом update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо! Только не применял обновление слоя, и так все работает.

Может кому пригодится - по клику создается новая метка, а старые удаляются.

```
    var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

    myMap.events.add('click', function (e) { 
        myCollection.removeAll();
        var coords = e.get('coordPosition');
        var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords); 
        myCollection.add(myPlacemark); 
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда у Вас много обьектов много маршрутов, есть вариант очистить карту полностью, для дальнейшей с ней работы:

```
cityCollection.removeAll();
myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
```